# How to make data in gridview cell a hyperlink to external site, changing the url at the same time

Tags: vb.net, url, gridview, hyperlink

Thank you for viewing my post. I am going to try to be clear as possible with my question. I have a gridview, with boundfields. I have a column, in which I want to make all data under the column a hyperlink to an external url.

The external url goes something like this. www.example.com/EX/EXX

The fields under the columns(that will be hyperlinks) would have something like this, EX EXX.

Is there a way to transfer that data into the URL? For example, EX in the cell would go where EX in the url is, and EXX in the cell will go where EXX in the url is.

If this doesn't make any sense, please let me know and I will clarify.

Thank you again for any help you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TemplateField` instead of a `BoundField` for the hyperlink, because you will be able to leverage the properties of the `<asp:HyperLinkField>` control, like this:

```
<Columns>
    ...
        Your bound fields here
    ...
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Title"
               DataTextField="Some Text"
               DataNavigateUrlFields="FieldThatHasEXValue, FieldThatHasEXXValue" 
               DataNavigateUrlFormatString="www.example.com/{0}/{1}" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. It's amazing how simple it is once you see the solution in front of you!

Comment: I do have another question, if you don't mind. I EX, and EXX data is actually in the same cell. So, cell 1 will read "EX EXX" Is there a way to split EX and EXX up with a "/" between them? I may be better off splitting the two in separate columns. Thanks again.

Comment: @Josh_with_questions - I think you are better off going with two separate columns.